# Too many commas?

Tags: commas

Is it just me, or are there too many commas in this sentence? If so, how would you revise it?

> If you are working with an outside vendor or organization requiring the firm logo, please forward the link to our logo usage page, which exists on our external website.

Comment: The commas are fine. _which exists_ is very unidiomatic.

Comment: When in doubt, leave it out.

Answer (score 1):

I'd drop the second comma and 'which exists':

> "If you are working with an outside vendor or organization requiring the firm logo, please forward the link to our logo usage page on our external website."

as they are not necessary to create a complete and understandable sentence.